Please help me with following limit related to Stolz–Cesàro theorem
If $x_1\in(0,1)$ and $x_{n+1}=x_n(1-x_n)$, find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}nx_n$ (Hint: using Stolz–Cesàro theorem)
I can prove that $x_n$ monotonically decrease and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=0$.Professor told me to use Stolz–Cesàro theorem, however I still cannot find the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}nx_n$.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Hint: Use Stolz-Cesàro on $$\frac{n}{\left(\frac{1}{a_n}\right)}$$ and notice that $\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{a_n}+\frac{1}{1-a_n}$.
